# How to switch between multiple scenes in Three js

Tags: three.js

I have a menu driven application that displays different Three js scenes. Whichever menu selection is chosen first is the one displayed regardless of menu selection.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to programmatically choose which scene is passed into the `render` function.  For example, say we have `scene1`, `scene2`, and `scene3`.

```
var sceneIndex = 2;
var currentScene = null;

switch (sceneIndex) {
    case 1:
        currentScene = scene1;

        break;
    case 2:
        currentScene = scene2;

        break;
    case 3:
        currentScene = scene3;

        break;
}

renderer.render(currentScene, camera);
```

Of course, there are more elegant ways to do this.

Comment: I would personally prefer some array selection like '''scenes = [scene1, scene2, scene3,..]  so you could easily say render.render(scenes[sceneIndex], camera)  this would deflate the switch-tree depending on how much scenes one wants to handle.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have created a sceneGroup array: sceneGroup[0], sceneGroup[1], and so on each with a different scene. If I first cause renderer.render(sceneGroup[1], camera) I get the appropriate scene. If I then cause renderer.render(sceneGroup[0], camera) I still get the former.

Comment: That should not be the case.  Have you verified that the values in the `sceneGroup` array are correct?

Comment: Yes. Reversing the sequence verifies the scenes. Whichever is rendered first, stays as though the renderer is not releasing the first scene rendered.

Comment: Do you use a different camera for each scene?  I do not know if that's necessary, but it may make a difference.

Another thing you can try is modifying the renderer's canvas domElement manually (e.g. drawing a rectangle on it to clear it) and seeing if it actually redraws over that.

Comment: Have tried creating an array of cameras as well to see if that were contributing to the issue. No effect. Have not tried the rectangle yet.

Comment: I'm sorry that my solution didn't work as expected.  Admittedly, I did not test it because the expected behavior of the `render` method is clear.  Perhaps use different renderers altogether, targeting the same DOM element?  As a last resort, you can just separate them altogether and use CSS to make the inactive ones invisible.

Comment: Added rendererGroup array. No effect. Amazing. I have searched for multiple scene sites and examples where switching between scenes would occur but have not come across any Three.js examples.

Comment: I've always had this question in mind , and this turns out to be the most elegant solution :)